# I need to know how this subroutine works

Tags: java

Sorry I'm a novice. please tell me why about the  subroutine and last System.out.print(d) are 2.
        # This problem has been solved

```
        public class practice2 
{
   static int d;
    static void aa()
    {
      int d=3;
      System.out.println(d); //d=3
    }
    static void bb()
    {
      d=d+1;
      System.out.println(d); //d=2
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     d=1;
     aa();
     bb();
     System.out.println(d); //d=2
    }

}
```

Comment: what else should it be?

Comment: aa() is print 3  but why bb() is not print 4 and last print is not 4 too?

Comment: I've explained that in my answer. You can check it there.

Comment: consider `static int d` as global whereas `int d = 3` as local variable. And the method call `bb();` changes the global and Sysout prints the global

Comment: @ambianBeing be careful about your choice of words. Java doesn't support global variables.

Comment: @Stultuske Yeah that was just for explanation. That's why I said to consider it and not meant it. But u are right.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void aa()
    {
      int d=3;
      System.out.println(d); //d=3
    }
```

Your aa() method uses a local variable d. this doesn't affect the value of the static variable d.

```
static void bb()
{
  d=d+1;
  System.out.println(d); //d=2
}
```

Your bb() method alters the value of the static variable d and prints that, since the value before was 1 (set in your main method), it now is 2.

You don't change this value after running bb.

Comment: @user13317921 if this answers your question, mark the question as solved.